# How to make this div appear outside of a container with overflow-y:auto?

Tags: css, sass, css-position

http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/waMpwZ

I'm building a hover div to be used in an Angular directive. This hover div appears anywhere there is a tag button. Currently my problem here is when the tag button is inside of this `tag-column` with the property `overflow-y: auto;` The hover appears stuck inside the column.

> I need the `overflow` property in order to allow scrolling inside of
>   the tag-column. Without it you can't scroll the tags.

[image]

```
<li>
  <div class="tag">Tag 1</div>
  <!-- below will appear on ^ tag hover -->
  <div class="tags-hover-container">
    <div>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

SCSS

```
.tag-column {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 300px;
    background: #ccc;
    z-index: 1;

    li { margin: 0; width: 100%; cursor: pointer; }
}

.tags-hover-container {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 20px;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    width: 230px;
    z-index: 10000;
    background: $gray_bg;
    border: 1px solid $gray2;
    @include rounded(3px);
}
```

Is there anyway to overcome this issue with CSS/SASS?
Or would I have to somehow rely on a Javascript(Angular) solution?

Comment: Just remove the `overflow-y` statement...I'm not sure why you need it. - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/waMpGL

Comment: @Paulie_D sorry I updated my codepen markup, I need it because I need to scroll the tags. There may be 100s of them.

Comment: Seems unlikely then...but someone cleverer than I may be able to help.

Comment: overflow-y:visible? seems to perform the same action as without any overflow at all [tested using Leon's codepen, didn't update though]

Comment: @BIW I just tried that.. but again I lost the scrolling inside of the `tag-column`

Comment: what about overflow on ul ? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BNjJzg

Comment: @GCyrillus oh! I think that may work :D Now I just need to make sure that the hover div appears below the correct tag, but this answers my question, do you want to post the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay, you could set overflow on ul instead the parent div.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

.tag-column {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  background: #ccc;
  z-index: 1;
}
.tag-column ul {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 300px;
}
.tag-column li {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tag {
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  width: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  clear: both;
  border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
  background: #F5F5F5;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.tags-hover-container {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 20px;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 230px;
  z-index: 10000;
  background: #F5F5F5;
  border: 1px solid #BFBFBF;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tag-column">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="tag">Tag 1</div>
      <!-- below will appear on ^ tag hover -->
      <div class="tags-hover-container">
        <div>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="tag">Tag 2</div>
      <!-- below will appear on ^ tag hover -->
      <div class="tags-hover-container">
        <div>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="tag">Tag 3</div>
      <!-- below will appear on ^ tag hover -->
      <div class="tags-hover-container">
        <div>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><div class="tag">Tag X</div></li>
    <li><div class="tag">Tag X</div></li>
    <li><div class="tag">Tag X</div></li>
    <li><div class="tag">Tag X</div></li>
    <li><div class="tag">Tag X</div></li>
    <li><div class="tag">Tag X</div></li>
    <li><div class="tag">Tag X</div></li>
    <li><div class="tag">Tag X</div></li>
    <li><div class="tag">Tag X</div></li>
    <li><div class="tag">Tag X</div></li>
    <li><div class="tag">Tag X</div></li>
    <li><div class="tag">Tag X</div></li>
    <li><div class="tag">Tag X</div></li>
    <li><div class="tag">Tag X</div></li>
    <li><div class="tag">Tag X</div></li>
    <li><div class="tag">Tag X</div></li>
    <li><div class="tag">Tag X</div></li>
    <li><div class="tag">Tag X</div></li>
    <li><div class="tag">Tag X</div></li>
    <li><div class="tag">Tag X</div></li>
    <li><div class="tag">Tag X</div></li>
    <li><div class="tag">Tag X</div></li>
    <li><div class="tag">Tag X</div></li>
    <li><div class="tag">Tag X</div></li>
    <li><div class="tag">Tag X</div></li>
    <li><div class="tag">Tag X</div></li>
    <li><div class="tag">Tag X</div></li>
    <li><div class="tag">Tag X</div></li>
    <li><div class="tag">Tag X</div></li>
    <li><div class="tag">Tag X</div></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

__ demo on line :http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BNjJzg